# How to find the timezone name from a tzfile in python

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-dateutil

Is it possible to get the inverse of this operation:

```
import dateutil.tz
tz_ny = dateutil.tz.tz.gettz('America/New_York')
print(type(tz_ny))
print(tz_ny)
```

This prints:

```
dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile
tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York')
```

How to recover 'America/New_York' given tz_ny of type tzfile?

N.B. `tz_ny.tzname(datetime.datetime(2017,1,1))` return 'EST' or 'EDT' if the date is in the summer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want just the timezone name from a `tzfile` and not the full path, you can e.g. do

```
import dateutil.tz
tz_ny = dateutil.tz.tz.gettz('America/New_York')

tz_ny_zone= "/".join(tz_ny._filename.split('/')[-2:])

print(tz_ny_zone)
```

which gets you

```
'America/New_York'
```

**EDIT**: Just for the sake of completeness, since the title only mentions `tzfile`: Besides `dateutil` there are other modules which can be used to get a `tzfile`. One way is using `timezone()` from the `pytz` module:

```
import pytz

tz_ny_pytz = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
```

Depending on which module you used in the first place, the class of `tzfile` differs

```
print(type(tz_ny))
print(type(ty_ny_pytz))
```

prints

```
<class 'dateutil.tz.tz.tzfile'>
<class 'pytz.tzfile.America/New_York'>
```

For the `pytz` object, there is a more direct way of accessing the timezone in human readable form, using the `.zone` attribute:

```
print(tz_ny_pytz.zone)
```

produces

```
'America/New_York'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there is a protected member variable....

```
tz_ny._filename
```

is

```
'/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
```