# How can I get the timezone from an Arrow date object

Tags: python, timezone, python-arrow

I need to retrieve the timezone from an Arrow date object

Let's take this as an example:

```py
import arrow
arrow_date = arrow.get("2000-01-01", tzinfo="America/Toronto")
```

How can I return this tzinfo exactly as it is in the code above?

I tried the following: `arrow_date.format("ZZZ")` but this returns an abbreviation that won't work in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `_filename` method of the tzinfo:

```
import arrow

arrow_date = arrow.get("2000-01-01", tzinfo="America/Toronto")
print(arrow_date.tzinfo._filename)
# Canada/Eastern
```

see also [How to find the timezone name from a tzfile in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46690771/10197418).

---

For a standard lib datetime object with tzinfo from `zoneinfo`, you can simply use the `__str__` method:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9

dtobj = datetime.fromisoformat("2000-01-01").replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/Toronto"))
tzinfo = str(dtobj.tzinfo)
print(tzinfo)
# America/Toronto
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I needed just the tzinfo object, and instead of using it from dateutil I used arrow.

Simple example:

```
utc = arrow.now('UTC').tzinfo
nyc = arrow.now('America/New_York').tzinfo

In [27]: nyc
Out[27]: tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York')
```